# DRY'ing up my views

Tags: django, django-models

I have this ugly pattern in my views.py where almost every method in my views consist of

`Products.objects.active().filter(user=request.user) # Return all products for the current user`

or

```
user = get_object_or_404(User, user=request.user)
products = user.product_set.all()
```

This is because every method is user dependent. Is there a way to extract this to my model or something DRY so I don't need to repeat myself in every method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you write a service function? Or decorate your functions with a user object if available?

```
services.py

def get_products(request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = request.user
    return somethings **depending** on the arguments passed...
```

and

```
views.py

def someview(request):
    context['user_products'] = services.get_products(request, commonCase)
    render ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [class-based generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/class-based-views/) and put the common code in a method on a base class. Something like this:

```python
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views import generic

class UserView(generic.View):
    """
    A generic view which requires an authenticated user and shows only
    active products belonging to that user.
    """

    def get_products(self):
        """
        Return queryset of products belonging to the authenticated user.
        """
        return self.request.user.product_set.all()

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(UserView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```